# Anime that I watched on Tubi around 2018 or 2019 about a girl who is part dragon, elemental powers, and enemy robots eating spicy sandwiches

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime was on Tubi around five or four years ago, 2018 or 2019.

The main character is a boy without parents, who grew up with an old man who is not related to him (or probably was, but he was probably also a headmaster or principal).

The main character has red hair and red eyes with a slightly old art style and he's still a kid, around 10-12. The plot is about him wanting to be a great something at the start (collector or master of something, I forgot).

He then meets a girl from out of nowhere who has pink hair and either blue or green eyes who we then find out is a part of the dragon that is the power source for all spirits or power in the world.

His dad died while time-traveling or something and his mom was found out to be a saint in the mountains.

The story has elemental power features where, based on your element, you get a mark on your forehead. The main character is fire and he has other friends who also are marked with different elements. We get a snobby and flamboyant-haired wind element boy with white hair and eyes, while others are obvious but the nature guy has long brown hair and green eyes.

He goes to a school where he eats a lot and then proceeds to get mocked and bullied by other kids. In the school they have them collect discs that hold "companions", which are like Digimon or spirits, which are also elemental based. Students fight and often trick each other for the discs and a rivalry begins.

The girl gets fed often by the main character in a cottage house. Nobody knows she's on campus since he's hiding her. The girl gets called a fairy by the MC and the girl is a pretty fellow so usually some boys blush throughout the episodes.

The girl is apparently a fragment of the dragon and needs to sacrifice herself in order to end some battle.

The villains or enemies are robots. There's a scene where the girl makes sandwiches but she always makes them too spicy. They find a traitor who unleashed robot dinosaurs upon the school who was actually disguised as a person, but was found out after they didn't react to the hellishly spicy sandwiches since they don't have taste buds.

They find a giant wormhole that was built to keep time-traveling machines.